# Fontcolor not working when footnote is continued at next page

Tags: color, footnotes

In the beginning of my document, directly after
`\begin{document}`, I put `\color{red}`. Unfortunatelly, on some pages, this does not work.

I found the cause, but not the cure: Footnotes which are too long for one page and are continued on the next page cause the page to change color. The page following is, as normal, again red.

So tell me: Why do the footnotes change the color of my page and how can I prevent them from doing that??

**Edit: Here is a minimal working example!**

**EDIT: The hints given below worked for me. Thanks a lot!**

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=12pt, xcolor=dvipsnames]{scrbook} % A4 paper and 11pt font size
%\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
% Biblatex

\usepackage[
style=numeric-comp,              % Zitierstil
isbn=false,                % ISBN nicht anzeigen, gleiches geht mit nahezu allen anderen Feldern
pagetracker=true,          % ebd. bei wiederholten Angaben (false=ausgeschaltet, page=Seite, spread=Doppelseite, true=automatisch)
maxbibnames=50,            % maximale Namen, die im Literaturverzeichnis angezeigt werden (ich wollte alle)
maxcitenames=3,            % maximale Namen, die im Text angezeigt werden, ab 4 wird u.a. nach den ersten Autor angezeigt
autocite=inline,           % regelt Aussehen für \autocite (inline=\parancite)
citetracker=true,          % I have no idea what this is
block=space,               % kleiner horizontaler Platz zwischen den Feldern
backref=false,              % Seiten anzeigen, auf denen die Referenz vorkommt
backrefstyle=three+,       % fasst Seiten zusammen, z.B. S. 2f, 6ff, 7-10
date=short,                % Datumsformat
hyperref=true,
backend = biber
]{biblatex}


\setlength{\bibitemsep}{1em}     % Abstand zwischen den Literaturangaben
\setlength{\bibhang}{2em}        % Einzug nach jeweils erster Zeile
\bibliography{report}  % Bibtex-Datei wird schon in der Preambel eingebunden

\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
%\usepackage{fourier} % Use the Adobe Utopia font for the document - comment this line to return to the LaTeX default

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm} % Math packages
\usepackage{bm} % boldmath



\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}  

% colorbox

\usepackage{empheq}

\newlength\mytemplen
\newsavebox\mytempbox

\makeatletter
\newcommand\mybluebox{%
    \@ifnextchar[%]
       {\@mybluebox}%
       {\@mybluebox[0pt]}}

\def\@mybluebox[#1]{%
    \@ifnextchar[%]
       {\@@mybluebox[#1]}%
       {\@@mybluebox[#1][0pt]}}

\def\@@mybluebox[#1][#2]#3{
    \sbox\mytempbox{#3}%
    \mytemplen\ht\mytempbox
    \advance\mytemplen #1\relax
    \ht\mytempbox\mytemplen
    \mytemplen\dp\mytempbox
    \advance\mytemplen #2\relax
    \dp\mytempbox\mytemplen
    \colorbox{Graybluelight}{\hspace{1em}\usebox{\mytempbox}\hspace{1em}}}


\usepackage{pgffor}
%\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry} % just to show the margins
%\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{minted} % needs '-shell-escape' to compile

% Bibliographie auf deutsch
%\usepackage{harvard}
%\renewcommand{\harvardand}{und} 
%\usepackage{caption}
\definecolor{gray1}{gray}{0.2}
\definecolor{gray2}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,0.8,1}
\definecolor{Grayblue}{RGB}{0,76,153}
\definecolor{Graybluelight}{RGB}{214,232,255}
\definecolor{Grayred}{RGB}{153,0,0}
\usepackage[font={color=gray1},figurename=Fig.,labelfont={color=Grayblue}]{caption}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{framed,color}
\usepackage{placeins}   % FloatBarrier
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{sidecap}
%\usepackage{float}      % adding boxes around figures
%\floatstyle{boxed}
%\restylefloat{figure}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{sectsty} % Allows customizing section commands
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{epigraph}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing


\usepackage{enumerate}

\renewcommand{\epigraphflush}{flushleft}

\hypersetup{
     colorlinks   = true,
     citecolor    = gray1,
     linkcolor    = Grayblue
}

\allsectionsfont{ \color{gray1} \normalfont\scshape} % Make all sections centered, the default font and small caps

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Custom headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy} % Makes all pages in the document conform to the custom headers and footers

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields

\fancyhead[LE]{\footnotesize \color{gray1}\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\footnotesize \color{gray1}\rightmark}%


\fancyfoot[LE]{\footnotesize \color{gray1}\sffamily\fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\selectfont\thepage}%
\fancyfoot[RO]{\footnotesize \color{gray1}\sffamily\fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\selectfont\thepage}%


\renewcommand\thefootnote{\textcolor{Grayred}{\arabic{footnote}}}
\addtokomafont{footnote}{\color{gray1}}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}



\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{pdfcolmk}
%\numberwithin{equation}{section} % Number equations within sections (i.e. 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4)
%\numberwithin{figure}{section} % Number figures within sections (i.e. 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4)
%\numberwithin{table}{section} % Number tables within sections (i.e. 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4)

%\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Removes all indentation from paragraphs - comment this line for an assignment with lots of text
%\setcapindent{1cm} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\title{
\normalfont \normalsize 
\textsc{ Mordor} \\ [25pt] % Your university, school and/or department name(s)
\horrule{0.5pt} \\[0.4cm] % Thin top horizontal rule
\huge \textsc{Kant and his special needs} \\ % The assignment title
\horrule{2pt} \\[0.5cm] % Thick bottom horizontal rule
}

\author{Bud Spencer} % Your name

\date{\normalsize\today} % Today's date or a custom date
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg, .eps}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% New Commands
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\horrule}[1]{\color{gray1}\rule{\linewidth}{#1}} % Create horizontal rule command with 1 argument of height
\renewcommand\theequation{{\color{Grayblue} \arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}}

\usepackage{kantlipsum,xcolor} 

\begin{document}

\color{red}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
    {\pagestyle{plain}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \tableofcontents
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \cleardoublepage}
\newpage


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CONTENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\setcounter{page}{1}
\kant[1-3] 
\footnote{\kant[4-5]} 
\kant[6-10] 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Without a minimal (non)working example it's hard to say. May be ask Pythia?

Comment: I did not use pythia! I am scared of creating a minimal example, because therefore I had to cut out quite a lot. I hoped that somebody might help me without.

Comment: Make a copy of your file and  post the cut out copy.

Comment: Pythia = Oracle at Delphi. The point is that our crystal balls are all out for repair so all we can suggest, if you don't want to reveal your code, is that you consult somebody who might have some insight into the problem without being given any information about it. Creating a minimal example may be tedious, but I've never seen it described as a source of terror before. Perhaps you have simply misunderstood the process involved?

Comment: Just give me some moments to create a minimalistic document in which the error is reproduced.

Comment: Try `\usepackage{pdfcolmk}` in the preamble

Comment: ***Without the code, we can't help.*** Please compile this: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum,xcolor}
\begin{document}
  \color{red}
  \kant[1-3]
  Some text\footnote{\kant[4-5]}
  \kant[6-10]
\end{document}`. As you see, the footnote is split between pages 1 and 2 but the text on pages 1, 2 and 3 is red. You just aren't giving us the information we need. Without that, all we can do is guess and that is a good use of neither our time nor yours.

Comment: The example really is not *minimal* That's a huge preamble! Try adding package `bigfoot` (just a guess in the dark – if it doesn't work take it away again. If you leave it in study its manual)

Comment: Also, even in your original document, your preamble would benefit from significant pruning. You are using obsolete packages which ought not be loaded at all, packages which would be better not loaded given your document class, packages multiple times with different options, and probably packages which you don't need. Presumably, `\color{gray1}` is responsible for changing the colour?